# Make the element auto and repeat scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, css, marquee

```
<div id="par">
  <div id="item11"></div>
  <div id="item12"></div>
  <div id="item13"></div>
  <div id="item14"></div>
  ....
</div>
```

I want to make the `div#itemXX` elements auto scroll up inside the `div#par`. Also I want it move one div each time.

I can use the `<marquee>` tag, but it has been deprecated, so I wonder if there other ways?

BTW, the height of the `div#itemXX` is not fixed.

**UPDATE:**
I want the "div#itemXX" move one each time. Just like the slide show,show one div each time,but if the current div's height is large than the viewport,it should scroll up,when the scroll end,the next div(slide) should move up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function(){
var top=0;
var par = document.getElementById('par')
var scroll = function() {
  top++;
  if( top>=par.firstElementChild.offsetHeight )
  {
    //first element is out of sight, so move to the end of the list
    top=0;
    par.firstElementChild.style.marginTop='';//reset to zero
    par.appendChild(par.firstElementChild);
  }
  else
  {
     //move the first element 'top' px up
     par.firstElementChild.style.marginTop='-'+top+'px';
  }
  setTimeout(scroll, 100);//repeat after 100ms
}
scroll();
})()
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/onohan/3/

Comment: Thanks,I upate my post,I want further effect.

Comment: @hguser: Then try to adjust the script. You also have to do something on your own, this is not a free coding service. Or pay someone to do it for you.

Comment: Move the setTimeout inside the if and the else, and make the timeout value bigger inside the if.